# what unit does joint controller use?

Tags: ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I sent joint controllers using radian to move the robot. See the [video example](https://community.gazebosim.org/t/physics-question-on-gazebo/1468/2?u=kakcalu13)

So this made me realized, what does the uni it use? Is it just rad only? The wheels are using joint_controllers btw.

Unfortunately, there is nothing mention on the [doc](https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.9/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1systems_1_1JointController.html#details). I doubt it's m/s or velocity. It's mostly working with rad to degree.

When I move the robot, it doesn't seem like a second to me. So that makes me wonder what unit is it using? So that way, i can figure the better and properly formula rather than throw sticks at it and hope for the best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28248/what-unit-does-joint-controller-use?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Oh, it's actually [velocity](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/joint_controller.sdf)

Interesting. If it's velocity then why did rad (degree * π/180) made the calculation working properly? Maybe its the formula that I was confused with.

If you know why, please comment because I'd love to know why!

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0